# What are the yellow stickers with the letter G and one or two arrows on some Japanese streets?

Tags: japan

I've been traveling around Japan recently and I've come across these stickers with the letter "G" and one or two arrows in many streets in Tokyo, Osaka and Kyoto.

[image]

Some streets have dozens of them. What do they mean?

Comment: Note that yellow letters on green ground however denote escape routes in case of godzilla attacks.

Comment: Along similar lines is when you're in California and you see "USA" spray-painted on a road or sidewalk.  It's not patriotic graffiti, but a mark of a buried pipe or cable; it stands for [Underground Service Alert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underground_Service_Alert).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It's a marker for a buried gas pipeline. Arrow points to where the gas heads to. The marker is used to easily identify which areas need to be dug up, in case maintenance (e.g. pipe replacement) is needed, or to avoid the pipes during excavation work.

Reference (in Japanese):
http://www.yotsugi.co.jp/products/detail/233

Comment: Why the Latin letter G and not the first Japanese character in the Japanese words  "gas"? Not universal or ISO enough?

Comment: @cat https://jisho.org/search/gas  It looks like only one character would not be sufficient to know what might be meant.

Comment: @cat I don't know the reason, but they sometimes use nails with the word for gas is spelled out. There are nails that also use just a G. See [link](http://www.ishiimark.com/catseye.htm)

Comment: gas in japanese is just ガス which is romanized as Gasu (and pronounced basically the same as terminal `u` are often ghosted), and all Japanese are required to study Japanese and so will know this romanization. why not ガ? I'm not sure...

Comment: @Andy: "G"' isn't sufficient to know what might be meant either (grain? glass? gum? gas?). It's a convention born out of the intention to keep things simple, and a similar convention could be drafted using a Japanese character.